# How to show notification in android with arabic text?

Tags: android, notifications

I developed android app which sends a notification in a particular time. The notifications works great and it shows arabic and english text well. but when i run the app on android device Nexus 5 with android version 5.1.1, the text notification in arabic appears as in a photo[image]

Here's the code i used..

```
        android.app.Notification notification = new  android.app.Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,ticker, System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(activity, title, text, pendingIntent);
    // Cancel the notification after its selected
    notificationIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
  //  notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

    notification.flags |= android.app.Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notification.defaults |= android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)activity.getSystemService(activity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Id++, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try To use Arabic Reshaper
I used it to display arabic in law APIs before
https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper/blob/master/src/org/amr/arabic/ArabicReshaper.java